# SVGO: Error "Invalid character entity"

Tags: svg

I am using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) (version 0.5.3) to minify my SVG files. Although the SVG can be opened in browser correctly, the minification gives error like:

> Error in parsing: Invalid character entity

My SVG file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg [
    <!ENTITY st2 "stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:6.6112;">
]>
<svg  width="48pt" height="48pt" viewBox="0 0 48 48" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="Layer_x0020_3">
        <g>
            <path style="&st2;" d="M41.7,35.3L26.6,9.4c-0.6-1-1.7-1.7-2.9-1.6c-1.2,0-2.3,0.7-2.9,1.7L6.3,35.4c-0.6,1-0.6,2.3,0,3.3c0.6,1,1.7,1.6,2.9,1.6h29.6c1.2,0,2.3-0.6,2.9-1.7c0.6-1,0.6-2.3,0-3.3z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I shrink the problem to the definition of `<!ENTITY...`. If I remove the definition of `<!ENTITY...`, SVGO doesn't report any error.

It seems the developers have realized this issue: [Error "Invalid character entity" for any input file](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/272). But they have not planed to fix it right now:

> As a temporary solution I recommend to turn off «Preserve Illustrator
>   Editing Capabilities» and some other advanced options, like including
>   XMP, in Illustrator SVG saving dialog.

However, we already have hundreds of SVG files in project. Is there any workaround?

Or could anybody recommend other tools to minimize SVG files?

Comment: You could batch process your files by running them through a script that will expand entities.  Anything that can read XML files and output the result would probably do.  For instance, xmllint might do the job (I haven't tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot find any solutions. So switch to [grunt-cleanhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-htmlclean), since we just need to remove the comments.